# What is the PowerShell equivalent to this Bash command?

Tags: powershell, grep, xargs

I'm trying to create a [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) command to have [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) check out all files that have a particular string in them. I primarily use [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), but the `tf` command has trouble resolving the path when run within the Cygwin environment.

I figure PowerShell should be able to do the same thing, but I'm not sure what the equivalent commands to [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) are.

So, what would be the equivalent PowerShell version to the following [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) command?

```
grep -l -r 'SomeSearchString' . | xargs -L1 tf edit
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using some UNIX aliases in PowerShell (like ls):

```
ls -r | select-string 'SomeSearchString' | Foreach {tf edit $_.Path}
```

or in a more canonical Powershell form:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String 'SomeSearchString' | 
    Foreach {tf edit $_.Path}
```

and using PowerShell aliases:

```
gci -r | sls 'SomeSearchString' | %{tf edit $_.Path}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to grok using a variable, e.g.,

```
PS> $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
       Select-String 'SomeSearchString' | 
       %{$_.path}  | 
       Select -Unique
PS> tf edit $files
```