# Powershell how to pipe into command object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pipe into powershell commands that I am dynamically retrieving.
So for example, if I get this command object

```
$ls = Get-Command 'Get-ChildItem'
```

How do I pipe anything to it?

I have tried:

```
'.\' | $ls
```

but I get an error that `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'm afraid your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me! It's worth noting that the `Get-Command` CmdLet returns an object, not a reference to the function! https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176842.aspx

Comment: Invocation operator `&` or `.` to the rescue: `'.\' | & $ls`.

Comment: Exactly, I have a command object that I get dynamically from a string.  I want to pass the contents of the pipeline to this command.

Comment: Thanks PetSerAl, that was easy!  If you want to add as answer, I'll accept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of xargs in PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36428949/1630171)