# Is there a way to remove all ignored files from a local git working tree?

Tags: git

Yesterday I spent several hours debugging a problem with my git repo that wasn't fixed by `git reset HEAD --hard` because the files causing the problem were ignored by `.gitignore`.  Is there a way to "flush" or "clean" a git repo of all files that are being ignored, so that only the files tracked by git are present?

I finally fixed my problem by deleting the repo and cloning it from github again, but in the future, I would like to immediately remove all potentially problematic files (those that are being ignored).

Comment: Try playing around with [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

Comment: The marked issue is not a duplicate. This talks about ignored files, the other one talks about untracked files.

Comment: @Patrick Please fix the answer or the title! The title says "all ignored" and not just "untracked"

Answer (score 284, accepted):

```
git clean -dfX
```

git-clean - Remove untracked files from the working tree
`-d` for removing directories
`-f` remove forcefully
`-n` Don’t actually remove anything, just show what would be done.
`-X` Remove only files ignored by Git. This may be useful to rebuild everything from scratch, but keep manually created files.

If the ignored files are already added to the index/staging, you must remove the files from the tracking index before using the above `clean` command.

`git rm -rf --cached .`

Then add the files except the ones included in the .gitignore file

`git add .` and create a commit with `git commit -m "message"`

Comment: In my case, because of the way the repo is configured to build projects with composer, I also needed to add the `-x` flag; `-df` alone didn't give me anything to remove.

Comment: @PatrickKenny That's a good one.. including it in the answer

Comment: this is completely incorrect answer! it talks about `untracked`, not `ignored` files.

Comment: You can also use the `x` flag instead of `X` to delete ignored *and* untracked files.

Comment: Doesnt remove ignored files.

Comment: @wilmol If the files are already added to the staging area, then the clean command cannot remove it. So you must remove the files from the staging first by `git rm -rf --cached .` and add the files except the ignored files in the staging area by `git add .`

Comment: @AlexSkrypnyk I think there is a confusion about the flags `-x`and `-X`.

Answer (score 36):

There is a single command solution:

```
git ls-files --ignored --exclude-standard | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs git rm -r --cached
```

What it does is:

- List all ignored files
- Handle paths with spaces to avoid failure
- Call git rm -r --cached to remove all the ignored files from index (without removing them from your local machine)

Comment: If you want to also delete them from the local machine just remove the --cached

Comment: Thanks!! This solution really works, the other answers don't actually remove the files on GitHub.

Comment: Very simple and nice solution. :-)

Comment: Using anything other than `-z` to handle files/paths with weird characters is an exercise in less-than-best-practice...

Comment: For anybody using this in 2022, you'll need the `-c` flag with `ls-files`:
`git ls-files -c --ignored --exclude-standard | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs git rm -r --cached`

Comment: A powershell equivalent based on [an answer from different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75323333/2620333), if you don't need the sed part:  `git rm -r --cached | ForEach-object {git ls-files -c --ignored --exclude-standard}`