# Build Row List dynamically using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have this requirement:

```
ListItem
--------
ABV
DEF
GED
ZAF
```

NOTE: ListItem is from an output of process one at a time.

```
foreach ($list in $listItem)
{  # Want to turn this into single row as each item get loaded
  ABV,DEF,GED,ZAF
}
```

What I have done to solve this is to land this entries into file first before processing with the code below

```
$list = Get-Content -Path C:\Ftest
[string]::Join(',' , $list) | Set-Content -Path C:\FFtestFinal
```

What I cannot figure out is how to build the list without landing it in a file. I want to land it directory in C:\FFtestFinal with the values 
`ABV,DEF,GED,ZAF`.

Comment: Are you asking "how to take multiple lines of output from a function and pass it as one line to another"? If so then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428950/4499969) answer may be of use to you.

Comment: Are you looking for `(... | Select-Object -Expand ListItem) -join ','`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$YourInput = 'ABV','DEF','GED','ZAF'
$YourInput -join ';'
```

Or (overall idea):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ';'
```