# How to remove old local Git branches on Windows?

Tags: git, powershell

I wanted to remove all my unneeded local Git branches, but [this guide](https://erikaybar.name/git-deleting-old-local-branches) I found online uses Bash. What is a more Windows native approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`select-string` as a replacement for `grep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) and this [PowerShell `xargs` replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428950/254477) this worked for me

```
,@( git branch -vv | select-string -Pattern 'origin/.*: gone]' | %{$_.toString().split(' ')[2].trim()} ) | %{&"git" "branch" "-d" $_}
```