# Force poetry to respect the versions in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

The following is in the *requirements.txt* :

```
requirements.txt:packaging==20.9
```

But then after doing a `poetry add [some unrelated pkg]`  We now have in the *poetry.lock*:

> {file = "packaging-21.3.tar.gz", hash =
> "sha256:dd47c42927d89ab911e606518907cc2d3a1f38bbd026385970643f9c5b8ecfeb"},

That is not going to work for us. How can I get poetry to listen to the requirements.txt?

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64787419/9215780) answer seems respect the version number. I ran it from windows power shell, it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get poetry to listen to the requirements.txt?

You cannot. Instead of using `requirements.txt` add your dependencies into the `pyproject.toml` if you use poetry.

Comment: Do you really expect us to manually add each requirement from requirements.txt into the pyproject.toml?