# How to overlay a logo to many images at once?

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

To overlay a logo in an image, I can use:

```
magick background.jpg logo.jpg -composite output.jpg
```

However, I don't know how to use this in batch. From [What's the equivalent of xargs in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428950/3416774), my try is:

```
,@(gci -recurse -file) | %{magick $_ ..\logo.png -composite output%d.png}
```

But it only produce one output `output0.png` which seems to be a [`-composite`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#composite) of all the images in the folder, not a list of new outputs which combine each image in the folder with the logo image.

This still works:

```
,@(gci -recurse -file) | %{Copy-Item $_ ..}
```

Comment: Remove `,@(...)`, it's forcing `ForEach-Object` to consume the whole inner array at once. `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | %{ magick $_.FullName ..\logo.png -composite output%d.png }`

Comment: Thanks. If I use an increment variable then it works: `$i=0; gci -recurse -file | %{$i+=1;magick $_.fullname ..\logo.png -composite a$i.png}`. But using the input name directly then it doesn't: `gci -recurse -file | %{magick $_.fullname ..\logo.png -composite a$_.name}`. Do you know why?

Comment: Parsing engine has two "modes" depending on whether it's parsing command arguments or value expressions. Change `a$_.name` to `"a$($_.name)"`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you want to make that an answer? Also, where should I read more about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use magick mogrify in Imagemagick to overlay a logo on many jpg images. Just keep the logo in a different directory if it is JPG also in this case so it is not tried to be put on itself. If it is PNG or some other format, then it can be in the same directory. First, cd to the directory holding your images. Then

```
magick mogrify -format jpg -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "path_to/logo.jpg"' *.jpg
```

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose

Answer (score 0):

My current working script:

```
gci -recurse -file | Foreach-Object {
    $out="new"+$_.name
    "Input = " + $_.name + "`nOutput = " + $out
    rm $out
    $bgWidth = $(magick identify -format %w $_.name) -as [float] 
    $bgHeight = $(magick  identify -format %h $_.name) -as [float]
    $logoWidth = $bgWidth*0.05 -as [float] 
    $logoHeight = $bgHeight*0.05 -as [float] 
    
    magick "..\Logo\logo1.png" -resize x$logoHeight logo1_resized.png
    magick "..\Logo\logo2.png" -resize x$logoHeight logo2_resized.png
    magick convert logo1_resized.png logo2_resized.png +append logo_stacked.png

    $logoOffset = $bgWidth*0.01
    
    magick $_ logo_stacked.png -gravity northeast -geometry +$logoOffset+$logoOffset -composite $out
}
```